# Transfer state from childComp to the parentComp

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have `two component`s and i need to transfer `stat`e from `children component` to the `parent component`

```
class Parent Component {
   this.state = {text: hahaha}
   this.props.action(text, data)

   <Children Component />
   <button onClick={this.props.action(text, data)}
}

class Children Component {
   this.state = {date: 12.12.12}
}
```

Another little tricky it's i have `redux-action` in Parent Component, that takes two parameters `text and date`, in sum when i click button i need to transfer `state` from `childComp` to the `parentComp` and then create action with two parametres in `parentComp`. So how i can do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Refer component communication](http://andrewhfarmer.com/component-communication)

```
class Parent extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            content: 'initial'
        }
        this.updateParentState = this.updateParentState.bind(this);
    }

    updateParentState(content){
        this.setState({
            content: content
        })
    }

    render(){
        let { content } = this.state;
        return <div>
            <Child updateParentState={this.updateParentState}/>
            <h1>{ content }</h1>
        </div>
    }
}

class Child extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            value: 'initial'
        }
        this.handleParentState = this.handleParentState.bind(this);
        this.changeContent = this.changeContent.bind(this);
    }

    handleParentState(content){
        let { updateParentState } = this.props;
        let { value } = this.state;
        updateParentState(content);
    }

    changeContent(event){
        this.setState({
            value: event.target.value
        })
    }

    render(){
        let { value } = this.state
        return <div>
            <input value={value} onChange={this.changeContent}/>
            <button onClick={this.handleParentState}>Update Parent State</button>
        </div>
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get state of child in parent component wil call back:

```
class Parent extends React.Component{
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {

        };
    }
    onClick(childState){
      console.log(childState); //see child state in parent component
    }
    render(){
      return <Child onClick={this.onClick} />;
    }
}
class Child extends React.Component{
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            first: "first",
            second: "second"
        };
    }
    render(){
      return <div onClick={() => this.props.onClick({...this.state})}>Click me</div>;
    }
}
```

Also You can use [redux](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html) or `ref`.